# IE 9 home page is hijacked by avg

Tags: internet-explorer, regedit, avg-antivirus, homepage

I definitely know how to change the home page in Internet Explorer (`Tools -> Options -> General`). The problem is, no matter what I put there, it never changes. Stop/restart Internet Explorer and the old home page is back.

I did some research to see if there is a registry key that I could tweak to get the home page to set properly. I changed the start page registry key and refreshed the view and the start page key (without even restarting `regedit`) was reset *back* to its original value.

Now I'm a little concerned. Maybe there's some virus I can't detect on my system?

```
Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
Windows 7 Pro SP 1 x64
```

Comment: Is the default home page malicious, or advertising, or something that would indicate it's a virus?

Comment: it's avg.com - ironically, an antivirus website. but it contains a guid in the url. prolly identifies me as me.

Comment: Is this 32 or 64 bit Windows 7?

Comment: windows 7 sp 1 64 bit

Comment: @horace: It's part of the [new user restrictions](http://superuser.com/privileges/new-user). They're meant to prevent spam and will disappear once you earn `10` rep.

Comment: @Dennis: thanks. i'm trying to clean up this post and my comments to be more consistent. seems like my edits are being modded somehow. i'll make sure to clean up my mess. =) ... now i just gotta 'member to come back in 2 days to check my answer as the 'accepted' answer. %-}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, folks. Here's what I had to do:

2. Go to the `Control Panel` -> Unistall programs and remove avg search tool: **that's** where it was, even though it was in my `IE` -> `Tools` -> `Manage add-ons`, I couldn't edit it because of the disabled 'remove' button when clicking on the avg search tool add-on. *(also, since this was a clean new install of Windows 7, I'm not sure how it got there in the first place. Never installed/used AVG in my life.)*
3. Go to the registry and edit the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes` and delete the DefaultScope entry
4. **Now** go to the `Tools` -> `Options` in IE and set the homepage to your heart's desire.

Simple as that.

To Lynn Crumbling for pointing out the AVG forum that led me to the regedit fix. But without removing the program from the Control Panel, this would simply do nothing, and come right back. Prolly a background process that manages the registry and crams the key back in place no matter what you do. Very clever, AVG.

<soapbox>

> this "avg hijack" is a commonly known and very unpopular "feature". Lots of people hate this kind of behavior, and it comes down to people like those on the AVG forum and myself to fix it all by our lonesomes.
>
> if I started writing software that behaves like this, I'd get lynched.

</soapbox>

Comment: FYI, you can answer your own questions. :)

Comment: well, at first, superuser wouldn't let me cuz i figgered it in under 8 hours, and they don't letcha answer your own question in under 8 hours. who'd'a thunk? i just fixed up the question, comments and my answer. thx!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread:

http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=188650

Sounds like your issue.

Specifically, the one poster says: "Thanks to help from others on the forum, I found the small Settings link and disabled it successfully."

See if you can find it too.

This page discusses it more thoroughly:
http://forums.avg.com/ww-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=188955#post_188955

> A few users mentioned on forums they would like to disable the AVG
>   default new tab page (which includes AVG secure search). This feature
>   could be disabled by clicking the Settings link in lower-right corner
>   of the newly opened tab (note the Settings link is not available on
>   home page, it is present only on newly opened tabs) as seen on this
>   screenshot.
>    - Modify the Show AVG Secure Search Box on new tabs in the browser as you wish.
>    - Click OK to save your configuration.

Comment: been looking thru this article. interesting.. tried a couple things but no go. also: the quote about 'disable avg search on new tab' is referring to firefox. my prob is for ie. i get avg search on a new browser window when starting ie. new tabs are clean.

Comment: also, i just tried editing: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes" to remove the DefaultScope, but after deleting it, the *%(&* thing just comes right on back.

Comment: thanks lynn.. the avg forum was a push in the right direction, but it took a little more oomph. see the answer i posted.

Comment: Just happy to see that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

With all the viruses and malware\spyware\adware floating around the Internet your problem could be caused by an infection. Some of these hijack your home page.

Do a complete virus scan and clean. Then run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system. A free online scan at eSet just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.

Comment: well, i just installed the os a couple days ago and haven't really done a bunch on it since. but since i *did* mention that it might be a virus, should do a deep scan first, huh?

Comment: Especially if you have no current protection.

Comment: just finished a deep scan and flash scan with malware bytes - all clean.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to viruses, many of the toolbars that you can download and install into IE will also hijack your homepage.  Some will politely ask you if you want to reset it to their homepage and others will just do it without telling you.  So if you added any toolbars, check their configuration options as they will often override IE's defaults with their own settings.

Comment: good thought. no toolbars installed. still looking for the "culprit"

Comment: When checking for toolbars and other add ons, go to `Tools`->`Manage Add ons`. Check all the sections there, and disable anything you can that you know you don't use

Comment: interesting. on 'Search Providers', AVG Secure Search is the default, enabled, and the 'remove' button is disabled for this selection. seems someone does not want me to remove avg as a search engine in ie..

Comment: I've seen several Anti-virus apps do that. McAfee tries to do that to me everytime I install a new update.  At least it asks me and lets me opt out of that.

Comment: bblake: i never had an "opt-in"/"opt-out" offer. not even sure how avg was installed in the first place. also, this was no trivial "change". see the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file to see if some odd network path has been set. A malicious entry in this file can route your browser through arbitrary sites...

Comment: only things not commented out are two lines: "0.0.0.0 .psf" and "0.0.0.0 psf"